# Is there a way to implement elif in list comprehension that also has a for loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to implement some list comprehension using both a for loop and an if statement with an elif statement.

Some background: I am importing data from sports-ref regarding basketball players. I wanted to create a list of all players that average at least 20 points per game this year, but I only want one instance of each player. For example James Harden has averaged more 20 or more points for multiple teams this season, and BBALLREF has a separate entry in his table for each team, and an additional one for the total from both teams. For my purposes I only need the total and am not interested in the data broken down by team. I have implemented list comprehension to compose the list of only 20 point scorers, but not such that it removes multiple instances of the same player and leaves only the total for said player.

Here is the code that reproduces the appropriate pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

# Grabs data from bball-ref
url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2021_per_game.html'
data = pd.read_html(url)[0]

# Removes all duplicate reminder label rows
data = data[~data.PTS.str.contains("PTS")]

# Converts all numerical data from strings to floats
for column in data:
    if data.apply(lambda s: pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').notnull().all()).loc[column]:
        data[column] = data[column].astype(float)

# Sorts players into the top scorers and removes duplicate players that have played for multiple teams
top_scorers = pd.DataFrame([data.loc[i, ['Player', 'Tm', 'PTS']] for i in data.index if float(data.loc[i, 'PTS']) >= 20]).sort_values('PTS', ascending=False)

print(top_scorers)
```

And Here is the output from the above code

```
                     Player   Tm   PTS
38              Bradley Beal  WAS  35.0
131             Kevin Durant  BRK  30.8
283           Damian Lillard  POR  29.1
231             Kyrie Irving  BRK  28.3
136              Joel Embiid  PHI  28.3
112            Stephen Curry  GSW  28.2
121              Luka Dončić  DAL  27.3
12     Giannis Antetokounmpo  MIL  27.3
506               Trae Young  ATL  26.9
448             Jayson Tatum  BOS  26.8
246             Nikola Jokić  DEN  26.8
310              CJ McCollum  POR  26.7
72              Jaylen Brown  BOS  26.6
270              Zach LaVine  CHI  26.6
278            Kawhi Leonard  LAC  26.3
239             LeBron James  LAL  25.0
189             James Harden  HOU  24.8
188             James Harden  TOT  24.4
190             James Harden  BRK  24.1
429            Collin Sexton  CLE  24.1
173             Jerami Grant  DET  23.7
162              Paul George  LAC  23.7
497          Zion Williamson  NOP  23.5
230           Brandon Ingram  NOP  23.4
502           Christian Wood  HOU  23.3
331         Donovan Mitchell  UTA  23.3
204           Gordon Hayward  CHO  23.0
69           Malcolm Brogdon  IND  22.9
59              Devin Booker  PHO  22.9
472           Nikola Vučević  ORL  22.5
402            Julius Randle  NYK  22.4
113            Anthony Davis  LAL  22.3
152             De'Aaron Fox  SAC  22.1
462       Karl-Anthony Towns  MIN  22.0
165  Shai Gilgeous-Alexander  OKC  21.8
326          Khris Middleton  MIL  21.2
422         Domantas Sabonis  IND  21.1
370           Victor Oladipo  HOU  21.0
486        Russell Westbrook  WAS  20.6
298          Lauri Markkanen  CHI  20.5
469            Fred VanVleet  TOR  20.4
368           Victor Oladipo  TOT  20.4
198            Tobias Harris  PHI  20.3
3                Bam Adebayo  MIA  20.1
369           Victor Oladipo  IND  20.0
```

As you can see, the resulting dataframe has three instances of James Harden, of which I would like to eliminate the two pertaining to HOU and BRK and keep the one corresponding to TOT. When I've tried to use and elif in-line with the list comprehension but python doesn't seem to recognize it as coupled with the if statement. If this turns out not to be possible with list comprehension, is there an easy way to do it with normal if and for statements, or even some other savvy way to pull this off?

Comment: You can do it with deleting duplicates, and keep the one that meets a condition, such as where Tm == TOT. I’m not near my laptop, so can do it a little later if someone doesn’t answer in the meantime.

Comment: you don't need a loop a here. `.drop_duplicates()` and `numpy.select` should be able to to this much faster than a standard python loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data = data[~((data[['Player']].duplicated(keep=False)) & (data['Tm'] != 'TOT'))]`

This will give you a slice of the dataframe, where we get rid of duplicate player names and their `'Tm'` isn't `'TOT'`

```
import pandas as pd

# Grabs data from bball-ref
url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2021_per_game.html'
data = pd.read_html(url)[0]

# Removes all duplicate reminder label rows
data = data[~data.PTS.str.contains("PTS")]

# Converts all numerical data from strings to floats
for column in data:
    if data.apply(lambda s: pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').notnull().all()).loc[column]:
        data[column] = data[column].astype(float)


# Sorts players into the top scorers and removes duplicate players that have played for multiple teams
top_scorers = pd.DataFrame([data.loc[i, ['Player', 'Tm', 'PTS']] for i in data.index if float(data.loc[i, 'PTS']) >= 20]).sort_values('PTS', ascending=False)


data = data[~((data[['Player']].duplicated(keep=False)) & (data['Tm'] != 'TOT'))] #<-- Gets rid of duplicate Player Names taht are not TOT
top_scorers = data[data['PTS'] >= 20].sort_values('PTS', ascending=False )
top_scorers = top_scorers[['Player', 'Tm', 'PTS']]

print(top_scorers)
```

**Output:**

```
print(top_scorers)
                      Player   Tm   PTS
38              Bradley Beal  WAS  34.8
131             Kevin Durant  BRK  30.8
283           Damian Lillard  POR  29.1
136              Joel Embiid  PHI  28.6
231             Kyrie Irving  BRK  28.3
112            Stephen Curry  GSW  28.2
121              Luka Dončić  DAL  27.2
12     Giannis Antetokounmpo  MIL  27.0
246             Nikola Jokić  DEN  26.8
448             Jayson Tatum  BOS  26.8
310              CJ McCollum  POR  26.7
506               Trae Young  ATL  26.6
270              Zach LaVine  CHI  26.5
72              Jaylen Brown  BOS  26.4
278            Kawhi Leonard  LAC  26.2
239             LeBron James  LAL  25.0
162              Paul George  LAC  24.4
188             James Harden  TOT  24.4
429            Collin Sexton  CLE  24.3
173             Jerami Grant  DET  23.7
497          Zion Williamson  NOP  23.7
230           Brandon Ingram  NOP  23.4
331         Donovan Mitchell  UTA  23.3
59              Devin Booker  PHO  23.1
204           Gordon Hayward  CHO  22.9
402            Julius Randle  NYK  22.6
472           Nikola Vučević  ORL  22.5
69           Malcolm Brogdon  IND  22.4
113            Anthony Davis  LAL  22.3
502           Christian Wood  HOU  22.3
152             De'Aaron Fox  SAC  22.3
462       Karl-Anthony Towns  MIN  22.0
165  Shai Gilgeous-Alexander  OKC  21.8
422         Domantas Sabonis  IND  21.6
326          Khris Middleton  MIL  20.7
486        Russell Westbrook  WAS  20.6
198            Tobias Harris  PHI  20.6
368           Victor Oladipo  TOT  20.4
469            Fred VanVleet  TOR  20.4
39             Malik Beasley  MIN  20.1
116            DeMar DeRozan  SAS  20.1
```

Comment: Great! this is exactly what I needed thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If-elif isn't possible in `list` comprehensions, but chained ternary expressions are:

```py
[x if cond1 else y if cond2 else z for thing in iterable_sequence]
```

Comment: BUT, you should also avoid writing complicated comprehensions.

Comment: I'd also suggest not using a `list` comprehension at all for your use-case. I'm really just answering the question in the title.